# How to get formatted google sheet data in HTML format

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't find a way to get formatted google sheet data in HTML format. I tried with Google Sheet API V4 grid data. But it is not easy to convert it to HTML format. Does anyone has a solution? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

[You could try this](https://medium.com/@stvhwrd/embedding-a-google-sheet-as-an-html-table-365306d2ec2c)

> To walk through a specific example, here (again) is our sample Sheet with some data.
>
> Double check the permissions on the file. In this case, the file is a
>   publicly-viewable example spreadsheet, so we’re good to go. Take the
>   URL of the Google
>   Sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit#gid=0
>   Notice that the Sheet ID in this case is zero: gid=0 Remove the
>   trailing edit#gid=… from the URL:
>   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/
>   Append the ✨magic string✨ (gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&) to the URL: 
>   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&
>   Append the Sheet ID (gid=0) to the URL:
>   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&gid=0
>   Done!